# Как реализовать создание схемы и таблиц в БД в самом коде (независимо от устройства)?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Как можно создать схему и таблицу в БД внутри само программы (в виде кода) без использования GUI MySQL? Чтобы при тестировании программы на другом компьютере все заработало. При этом, чтобы не возникало ошибки "таблица с таким именем уже существует".

Comment: Использовать соответствующие инструменты для работы с СУБД языка, на котором хотите писать код. Чтобы не возникало ошибки, во многих СУБД поддерживается запрос `CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS]`.

Comment: Ваша программа должна выполнить sql-запросы создания БД, таблиц и всего остального: `create database ...`, `create table ...`. Можно сгенерировать их автоматически в Workbench или другой утилите для работы с mysql. А потом просто скопируйте их в свой код.